# In local environment, should I use docker-compose or kubernetes (minikube)?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

I've already some environments setted with docker and docker compose, so I have diferent containers with diferent services, and all of them are orchestrated by docker-compose, and it works ok in my local dev environment. Recently I've read about kubernetes and minikube, but aparently, kubernetes is a tool more for servers/clusters of containers management.

The question is, for a local dev environment (php, mysql and apache for example), what container orchestration mechanism should I use?

Comment: This class of question is one we actually tend not to permit here. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, particularly #4 in the "some questions are still off-topic" list, emphasis added: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, **tool**, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Comment: sorry, and thanks for clarifying me.

Comment: though good question..i wonder should this be under 'design'?

Comment: it's a good question and should be permitted.

Answer (score 12):

There are lots of decision criteria. If there is a target environment for this application- use local tools that best approximate that target environment. If the target environment runs kubernetes, best to use minikube. If the target environment is some flavor of clustered docker, use compose. If there is no target environment, use whatever you're most comfortable with or want to learn.